# ColdFusion ORMExecuteQuerygetting last record

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I have a query in mysql below

```
SELECT newsletterKey 
FROM tblnewsletter
ORDER BY newsletterKey DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Now when i am use above query in ORMExecuteQuery like

```
ORMExecuteQuery("FROM Newsletter ORDER BY newsletterKey DESC LIMIT 1");
```

It display me all records instead of last record

Comment: have you tried to dump query?

Comment: I have got it using query 
ORMExecuteQuery("FROM Newsletter ORDER BY newsletterKey DESC", false, {maxResults=1} );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIMIT is not supported in HQL that's why.

like you said,

```
ORMExecuteQuery("FROM Newsletter ORDER BY newsletterKey DESC", false, {maxResults=1})
```

would work.